# Где посмотреть информацию, что такое версии инфоблоков 1.0 и 2.0 в Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Готовлюсь к зачёту и не могу найти ответ на вопрос что такое версии инфоблоков 1.0 и 2.0, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://bx-cert.ru/certification/bitrix/4/344/ ?

Comment: @gil9red да спасибо, но как понять что эти инфоблоки версии 1 или 2, не могу понять в какой таблице хранят свои свойства инфоблоки версии 2, по версии 1 много информации

Comment: В таблице b_iblock у инфоблока есть поле «VERSION» - обозначает версию. Но проще всего зайти в настройки инфоблока, и смотреть поле «Значения свойств хранятся». Для версии 2.0 будет значение «в отдельной таблице для данного информационного блока», для версии 1.0 - «в общей таблице (по умолчанию)».